# Vector cross product identity for $(a\times b)\cdot(c \times d)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products, cross-product

Prove that

$(a\times b)\cdot(c \times d)=(a\cdot c)(b\cdot d)-(a\cdot d)(b\cdot c)$

I would appreciate some hints on how to solve this. I assume there is a method which does involve equating  LHS and RHS by break them into components which would be extremely tedious to say the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be helpful if you first introduce a new symbol to refer to one of the vector cross-products as a whole. E.g., let's define $(a\times b)=:x$. Using the cyclic property of the scalar triple product, we equate the scalar quadruple product to the dot-product of one of the vectors with the vector triple product of the other three:

$$\begin{align}
(a\times b)\cdot(c\times d)
&=x\cdot(c\times d)\\
&=d\cdot(x\times c)\\
&=d\cdot\left[(a\times b)\times c\right].
\end{align}$$

Expanding the triple product via Lagrange's formula,

$$(a\times b)\times c=(c\cdot a)b-(c\cdot b)a,$$

we can substitute this back into the formula above. Distributing the dot product with $d$, we find:

$$(a\times b)\cdot(c\times d)=(c\cdot a)(d\cdot b)-(c\cdot b)(d\cdot a).~~\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(a\times b)\cdot c=[(c\cdot b)a-(c\cdot a)b$$
$$(a\times b)\cdot (c\times d)$$
Taken $c\times d=x$
$$=[(a\times b)\cdot x]_i$$
$$=x_i\epsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k$$
$$=a_j\epsilon_{jik}x_ib_k$$
$$=[a\cdot (x\times b)]_j$$
$$=[a\cdot ((c\times d)\times b]_j$$
$$=[a\cdot[(b\cdot d)c-(b\cdot c)d]]_j$$
$$=[(a\cdot c)(b\cdot d)-(b\cdot c)(a\cdot d)]_j$$